# Include file with duplicate class

Tags: php, oop, classname

I want to include a file which contains a class that already exists in my application.  Obviously this results in:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class XYZ
```

For reasons I won't go in to here, I cannot change the code of the file in question, nor the file which contains the original class.  For this reason, I don't *think* that namespaces are an option - though I'm a bit new to the concept so I could be wrong.

- Is there a way to dynamically change the contents of the file being read to change classname declaration on the fly?
- Can I somehow destroy or *un-include* the duplicate class which already exists?

I realize this is not likely to be clean.  Any ideas for a workaround no matter how ugly are welcome.

Comment: If you rename the class, the callers won't know to use the new name. And if you destroy the duplicate that already exists, what happens to all its callers? This is what class namespaces were created to solve.

Comment: I don't think you can undeclare. You probably need to make a `namespace`.

Comment: @Barmar - I don't think either of those things are an issue.  I just need to access the class methods.  I can reload the original class if need be.

Comment: @Rasclatt - I know absolutely zilch about how to use namespaces to make this work.  Does it need to happen in the class declaration itself?  If so, that won't help me since I can't modify the file being included.  If not, please advise.

Comment: Is the class the exact same class, you are just including it again (for whatever reason)? If so, use `include_once()`

Comment: No it's a completely different class which just coincidentally has the same name as something else in the application.

Comment: Ok, then you definitely need to look up `Namespace` on the php manual. You have to either rename the class or use the `namespace`

Comment: @Rasclatt - Since I cannot modify the file, is using a namespace still an option?  If so, can you provide an example?

Comment: There's a tutorial at http://www.sitepoint.com/php-53-namespaces-basics/. You can put your own class in a namespace, then it won't conflict with the file you can't modify.

Comment: No, I cannot modify the original class either.

Comment: Basically, I am stuck with two classes that can't be modified and have the same name.  I'd like to know if there's a way to include them both without having the ability to change the file contents.

Comment: Not to my knowledge there is no way to do that. You are pretty much stuck if you cannot modify either of the classes either by namespace or by renaming.

Comment: Is there possibly a way to load the contents into a buffer, modify the contents and then 'include' the buffer?  I could conceivably just write it to a temp file with a namespace...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question here per the idea mentioned in comments.

```
$path = "/path/to/include/file.php";
$className = "OriginalClassname";
$tempClass = "ReplacementClassname";

$buffer = file_get_contents($file);
$buffer = str_replace($className,$tempClass,$buffer);
$file = 'temp.php';
file_put_contents($file, $buffer);
include_once($file);
unlink($file);
```

In a nutshell:

- read the file to a variable
- replace the classname
- write the variable to a temporary file
- include temp file
- remove temp file

Worked like a charm.